# Find polynomial relationship between two pandas df columns and extend it to the rest of the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, polynomials

Herebelow is an example of my dataset:

```
[index] [pressure] [flow rate]
0         Nan            0
1         Nan            0
2         3              25
3         5              35 
4         6              42
5         Nan            44
6         Nan            46
7         Nan            0
8         5              33
9         4              26
10        3              19 
11        Nan            0
12        Nan            0 
13        Nan            39
14        Nan            36
15        Nan            41
```

I would like to find a polynomial relationship between the pressure and flow rate where the data for both are present (in this example we can see there are data points for both pressure and flow rate from index 0 to index 4), and then I need to extend the values of pressure for Nan values based on the polynomial relationship that I found above up to the point where the data for both are present again (in this case the data is again present from index 8 to index 11), in which case I need to find a new polynomial relationship between pressure and flow rate and extend the pressure values further based on my new relationship up to the next available data and so on.
I appreciate any advice on how best to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You can `interpolate`:

```
df['[pressure 2]'] = df.set_index('[flow rate]')['[pressure]'].interpolate('polynomial', order=2).values
```

Output

```
    [index]  [pressure]  [flow rate]  [pressure 2]
0         0         2.0           21      2.000000
1         1         4.0           29      4.000000
2         2         3.0           25      3.000000
3         3         5.0           35      5.000000
4         4         6.0           42      6.000000
5         5         NaN           44      6.000000
6         6         NaN           46           NaN
7         7         NaN           50           NaN
8         8         5.0           33      5.000000
9         9         4.0           26      4.000000
10       10         3.0           19      3.000000
11       11         6.0           44      6.000000
12       12         NaN           41      5.915690
13       13         NaN           39      5.578449
14       14         NaN           36      5.044156
15       15         NaN           40      5.775173
```

*NB. The remaining NaNs cannot be interpolated without ambiguity, you can `ffill` if needed*

Comment: Anything incorrect? A comment would be appreciated

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks for this answer. I am just testing it rn, will let you know.

Comment: I tried applying 'interpolate' as suggested, but it raises an error "ValueError: Expect x to not have duplicates". Perhaps, it is due to my dataset being large and it contains duplicates of x. Is there another pythonic way of coding this up? For instance, I am assuming if we find a polynomial relationship and then applying the equation to find the rest of the pressure values.

Comment: Can you update your example?

Comment: I updated the dataset, I hope it reflects more or less my real dataset. Basically, I need to establish the polynomial relationship where ever the data for both pressure and flow rate exist and then interpolate the pressure data for the part where the data for flow rate is present. The parts where the flow rate is zero, obviously the pressure will be zero. Thanks again), just to clarify I should be able to interpolate pressure values for indices 5,6,13,14,15